# How do I count the number of occurrence of an item in a list? - Dart

Tags: dart

I would like to know how many occurrences of a single item consists in a list in dart. As far as I know, the contains method checks only up to the first occurrence and returns a bool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following counts how many "1"s are in list:

```dart
[1, 2, 1].where((item) => item == 1).length
```